# Docusaurus: Make a shared links template for all pages

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus

### What I want to accomplish

In docusaurus I want to have a single file where I can declare all the links in my docs, preferably using links to the **md** file that are processed by docusaurus.

### Description of my issue

This is my first time working with docusaurus and with anything react.js

I've been building an **user manual** with pictures, videos tutorials and text. To improve readability for my **non-tech** users, I´ve been adding links to related pages in my docs.

For example:

[image]

If we looked at my .md file I would have something like this:

```
Para que un [operador][concepto__OperadorUrl] pueda acceder al sistema deberá 
solicitar un [**usuario nuevo**][auth__UsuarioNuevoUrl]
```

and the links would be declared like this:

```
[concepto__OperadorUrl]: /docs/conceptos.md#operador
[auth__UsuarioNuevoUrl]: /docs/auth/users.md#newUser
```

I´m going to be using these links many times all over the documentation. I would like to keep the docs as DRY (**D**on´t **R**epeat **Y**ourself) as possible. It would be awesome if I could declare these links in a single md file, json or js file, and use them all over.

### What I´ve tried

---

**version 1**

Using a template as _CommonSharedUrl.mdx

```
import ConceptoOperadorUrl from '/';
```

and importing it into one of my .md files

```
import SharedUrls from '/docs/shared/_CommonSharedUrl.mdx'

<SharedUrls />
```

and using it like this

```
[shared url]({ConceptoOperadorUrl})
```

or like this

```
[shared url](ConceptoOperadorUrl)
```

but i always get an error saying

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/'**

---

**version 2**

Using a template as _CommonSharedUrl.mdx

```
[shared_url]: /ConceptosBasicos#operador
```

and importing it into one of my .md files

```
import SharedUrls from '/docs/shared/_CommonSharedUrl.mdx'

<SharedUrls />
```

and using it like this

```
[shared url][shared_url]
```

still doesn´t work an i get the result

[image]